# Hide ActionBar Android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, xamarin

I don´t know why this code is not working it should be easy I looked for asnwers and all of them say same. I want to hide the action bar in my android app. This is my Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1.0" 
          package="com.companyname.nucleo">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" 
               android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  </application>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

And here is my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name = "android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name = "android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the *parent* atribute to add "...*NoActionBar*".

Like this:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: please mark your reply as answer to close your thread.

Answer (score 3):

Add this in you style.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>
```

And add this to activity tag in manifest.

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Example:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.YourActivityName"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: I edit my code. But it still not working. I don't know why. It sould be easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide actionbar, you can try the following code:

1. Hide Action Bar permanently from styles.xml.

Navigating to **resources > values > styles.xml** and change your Base application theme as mentioned below.

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

2. Hide Action Bar with custom Theme

Sometimes you want to style your app in a custom way, and there is a requirement to hide the Action Bar. A simple and convenient method is to create another style extending the custom theme and add two items to the theme.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimary">#5A8622</item>

<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

then using this style in Mainactivity.cs:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class **MainActivity : Activity**
{
```

Please note: if you want to use the second method to hide actionbar, the MainActivity is inheriting Activity.

Comment: I edit my code. But it still not working. I don't know why. It sould be easy.

Comment: @DavidZarzosoMoreno you are MelbinKJoseph? If yes,please use MelbinKJoseph account to reply. And you can provide one sample at github, I will help you to test at my side.

Comment: No, I'm David. I solved it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use C# Attirbute to set a theme on Xamarin

```
// write theme here to apply
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.MyTheme.NoActionBar")
public partial class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
   ...
}
```